# Selecting random sample of data from data table based on multiple condition in R

Tags: r

I have a large dataset of about 11 million rows in a data table. I would like to generate a random sample of rows based on multiple conditions. Below is the sample dataset with desired output.

```
Var  Code  Count_Curr        res
1     146   1649             0.05
1     147   1649             0.05
1     148   1649             0.1
1     149   1649             0.06
1     150   1649             0.01
1     151   1649             0.1
1     152   1649             0.06
1     153   1649             0.1
2     146   1649             0.05
2     147   1649             0.05
2     148   1649             0.1
2     149   1649             0.06
2     150   1649             0.01
2     151   1649             0.1
2     152   1649             0.06
2     153   1649             0.1
3     146   1649             0.05
3     147   1649             0.05
3     148   1649             0.1
3     149   1649             0.06
3     150   1649             0.01
3     151   1649             0.1
3     152   1649             0.06
3     153   1649             0.1
```

My Desired output after sampling should be like

```
Var  Code  Count_Curr        res
1     146   1649             0.05
1     147   1649             0.1
1     146   1649             0.06
2     146   1649             0.05
2     147   1649             0.1
2     146   1649             0.06
3     146   1649             0.05
3     147   1649             0.1
3     146   1649             0.06
```

I would like to select 5 or 10 codes from each "var" and it should also cover from all "res" available for that "var".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want but maybe with the `caret` package and `createDataPartition` function in order to keep Var frequences similar to the original data frame :

To select 10% of the lines :

```
indexes <- createDataPartition(df$var,times = 1,p = 0.1,list = FALSE)
df.sample <- df[indexes,]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be achieved using the dplyr package.

dat %>% group_by(Var, res) %>% sample_n(5, replace=FALSE)

which relies on there being 5 rows for each {Var res} combination; if that's not the case, you'll need to specify what you want to happen in such situations.

EDIT - re-reading, you'll need different approaches if there are more or less than 5 different res in a particular Var.  It's not quite clear which will be the case, but you could probably achieve something workable replacing the '5' with '1' in the above code.